# c# WPF update dataset specific columns not working

Tags: c#, wpf

Overall goal: Trying to to have a button that displays on every row that closes a the ticket (changes open state column to 0 and updates the closeddate column with datetime).

Stuff done so far: I have the button being created and displaying with the dataset. However, I can't figure out for the life of me how to get to update only those two columns (openstate, closeddate).

I'm using the default query builts as much as possible which might be my problem.

In efferts to not make you read all of the code i'll put as little as possible. if you need more please let me know and i'll add all it if you want.. Newbie at this so just let me know what you need :).

xaml:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgtask" Background ="Black"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"
                        Binding="{Binding Path='taskTitle'}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                        Binding="{Binding Path='taskDesc'}" />


            <!-- Add your normal columns here -->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="btnclose" Click="btnclose_Click">My button</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

behind code:

```
        private void btnclose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
        _dsTaskTracker = new TimeTrackerDataSet();
        _taTaskTracker = new TimeTrackerDataSetTableAdapters.taskTableAdapter();
        _dtTaskTracker = new TimeTrackerDataSet.taskDataTable();
        _taTaskTracker.Update("I can't figure out how to limit this to only the two columns");
    }
```

It's not picking all of it right sorry for the sloppy mess
dataset code:

```
   this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE [dbo].[task] SET [taskTitle] = @taskTitle, [taskDesc] = @taskDesc, [creation] = @creation, [closed] = @closed, [taskOpen] = @taskOpen WHERE (([titleID] = @Original_titleID) AND ([taskTitle] = @Original_taskTitle) AND ((@IsNull_taskDesc = 1 AND [taskDesc] IS NULL) OR ([taskDesc] = @Original_taskDesc)) AND ((@IsNull_creation = 1 AND [creation] IS NULL) OR ([creation] = @Original_creation)) AND ((@IsNull_closed = 1 AND [closed] IS NULL) OR ([closed] = @Original_closed)) AND ((@IsNull_taskOpen = 1 AND [taskOpen] IS NULL) OR ([taskOpen] = @Original_taskOpen)));
SELECT titleID, taskTitle, taskDesc, creation, closed, taskOpen FROM task WHERE (titleID = @titleID)";

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.Text;

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@taskTitle", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskTitle", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@taskDesc", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskDesc", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@creation", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "creation", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@closed", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "closed", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@taskOpen", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskOpen", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_titleID", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "titleID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_taskTitle", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskTitle", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_taskDesc", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskDesc", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_taskDesc", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskDesc", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_creation", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "creation", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_creation", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "creation", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_closed", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "closed", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_closed", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "closed", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_taskOpen", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskOpen", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_taskOpen", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "taskOpen", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@titleID", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "titleID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
```

Comment: Could you show us your `TimeTrackerDataSet` and `TimeTrackerDataSetTableAdapters`?

Comment: I can you want the whole thing or any perticler section.. it's rather large?

Comment: @Alex I added some code. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: The `updatecommand` will not update the `openstate`, I think you may need to find another update method, or override the `updatecommand` if it have exposed...

Comment: @Alex I'm not against that idea, but can't figure out a way to do that :). I orginally thought I could update the data and update the data in a sequence step. first update the data then refresh the data set on page. but now i'm just about ready to try anything to get past this darn part..

Comment: @Alex i'm almost wondering if i could handle the datetime update with a function or trigger on the database when ticket is close update closeddate column..